# How to filter specific tables in mk-parallel-dump

Tags: mysql, dump

I'm trying to filter on specific tables when using mk-parallel-dump.

I've got 10 tables that all start with mediadb_ . I've tried to use commands as:

```
mk-parallel-dump --numthread 8 --database p2g_lorem_e10 --tblregex "^mediadb_\w*" -v --basedir ./
```

and

```
mk-parallel-dump --numthread 8 --database p2g_lorem_e10 --tblregex "^mediadb_" -v --basedir ./
```

but everytime I only get "No tables to do for set default" back. What does this message mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-dump.html), the regex need to be in PERL compatible.

A workaround will be using option `--tables`

```
mk-parallel-dump --tables mediadb_tb1,mediadb_tb2,mediadb_tb3,...
```